# Looping through dictionary problem - Value duplicated

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking for help. I can't see where the problem is.
Please be gentle, I'm a complete beginner.

I have a dictionary - key = name, value = language
I also have a list of names

The task is to loop through the list and print different messages depending if the name in the list is also in the dictionary.

My loop works :

```
fav_lan={"Zuza":"Python","Ago":"C","Jessie":"Python","Maria":"Java","Lou":"Python","Edo":"Java","Yvonne":"C"}

p_list=["Jenny","Lou","Zuza","Robert","Ago","Adam"]

for person in p_list:
    if person in fav_lan:
        print(f"Hi {person}, thank you for voting")
    else:
        print(f"Hi {person}, you need to vote first")
```

I also wanted to add sentence stating the language for every name that appears in the dictionary:

```
fav_lan={"Zuza":"Python","Ago":"C",
         "Jessie":"Python","Maria":"Java",
         "Lou":"Python","Edo":"Java","Yvonne":"C"}

p_list=["Jenny","Lou","Zuza","Robert","Ago","Adam"]

for person in p_list:
    if person in fav_lan:
        print(f"Hi {person}, thank you for voting, your favorite language is:")
        for language in fav_lan.values():
            print(fav_lan[person])
    else:
        print(f"Hi {person}, you need to vote first")
```

Code runs but prints language 7 times (this is the number of values in the dict).

Could someone please point out the error.

I tried using set()
Got the number of languages duplicates to 3 - I consider this a poor success.

Comment: Just remove the `for language in ...` line and unindent the subsequent print statement. You don't need to loop over the languages at this point because you know the person's favorite language (it's `fav_lan[person]`).

Comment: Hi Jarmod, makes sense ... now that you pointed it out. Thank you

Comment: Try `print(f"Hi {person}, thank you for voting. Your choice was \"{fav_lan[person]}\"")`